# how to find and copy files in a sub directory from parent directory linux

Tags: linux, find, exec, xargs, cp

I have several parent folders like GJ1, GJ2 etc. Each of these folders contain three images like **GJ11_F.jpg**, GJ11_P.jpg. I need to only display all the **GJ11_F.jpg** files including their respective **parent** directories.

```
    find . -type f -name "*_F.jpg" | xargs cp -t ~/home/ubuntu/
```

but the above command will only copy the ***_F.jpg** files and not their respective parent directories GJ1.

Is xargs not the one im supposed to try?

I have also tried -

```
    find . -name "*_F.jpg" -exec sh -c 'rsync -a "${0%/*}" ~/home/ubuntu/' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to use `tar` which will deal with the directories automatically:

```
find . -type f -name "*_F.jpg" -print0 | tar c --null -T - | tar xC ~/home/ubuntu/
```

And here's a solution with a `while` loop:

```
find . -type f -name "*_F.jpg" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        mkdir -p ~/home/ubuntu/"$(dirname -- "$file")"
        cp -ai -- "$file" ~/home/ubuntu/"$file"
    done
```

Comment: Thanks! the script works fine but not the find command piped to tar.